# Automatic Django API test using Github action failed

Tags: django-rest-framework, automated-tests, http-post, github-actions

I wanted to test automatic testing during each push in Github. So I wrote a basic API and test cases. In the local machine where I am using ubuntu, all are working fine. I uploaded the code in a GitHub repository and and wrote the GitHub workflow like below:

```
  name: testing
  
  on:
  
    push:
      branches: [ main ]
    pull_request:
      branches: [ main ]
  
  jobs:
    test-code:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: Checkout repo
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Set up python
          uses: actions/setup-python@v2
          with:
            python-version: 3.8.8
        - name: Caching
          uses: actions/cache@v2
          with:
            path: $/{/{ env.pythonLocation /}/}
            key: $/{/{ env.pythonLocation /}/}-$/{/{ hashFiles('setup.py') /}/}-$/{/{ hashFiles('requirements.txt') /}/}
  
        - name: Install dependencies
          run: python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
  
        - name: Run django integratin test
          run: python manage.py test
```

My test code is like belwo:

```
        PREDICT_API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict/'
        
        class PredictApi(TestCase):
            '''
            Using postman these can be tested as well.
            '''
        
            @tag('important')
            def test_predict_negative(self):
                # python manage.py test predict.tests.PredictApi.test_predict_negative
        
                data = {
                    "cough": [0],
                    "fever": [0],
                    "sore_throat": [0],
                    "shortness_of_breath": [0],
                    "head_ache": [0],
                    "age_60_and_above": [0],
                    "gender": [0],
                    "test_indication": [0]
                }
        
                response = requests.post(PREDICT_API_URL, json=data)
                results = response.json()
        
                assert results['corona'] == 0
```

But when I am pushing to GitHub I am getting connection error.

[image]

I am learning Github actions. It will be good if I make it run. The Github link of this is: https://github.com/bikashckarmokar/covid_prediction